# Retain iframe src from dropdown menu after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have created a dropdown list that will update the iframe src, however how can I make sure that when I refresh the page the iframe src will not change unless the user changes it from the `dropdown menu` using `JavaScript`?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span9">
        <select onchange="loadFrame(this.value,'starterVID');this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option>Choose A View</option>
          <option value="yahoo.com>Vid02</option>
          <option value="youtube.com/">Vid03</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid04</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid05</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid06</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid07</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid08</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid09</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="flex-video widescreen vimeo">
          <iframe name = "starterVID" 
                  id = "starterVID" 
                  width="870" 
                  height="498" 
                  src="https://www.youtube.com/" 
                  frameborder="0" 
                  allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use cookies to store the value of previously selected option and use that if it exist?

Comment: Use either cookies, local storage or URL params to store the current user selection. When page loads read the value from one of those places. The best way is to use URL params since it will retain it's properties with the URL itself.

Comment: @Thusitha can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/cb10bwkL/2/

```js
loadFrame = function(val, id){
  localStorage.setItem(id, val);
  $('#' + id).attr('src', val);
}

if(typeof localStorage.getItem('starterVID') != 'undefined'){
  $('select').val(localStorage.getItem('starterVID'));
  $('#starterVID').attr('src', localStorage.getItem('starterVID'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span9">
        <select onchange="loadFrame(this.value,'starterVID');this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option>Choose A View</option>
          <option value="yahoo.com">Vid02</option>
          <option value="youtube.com">Vid03</option>
          <option value="google.com">Vid04</option>
        </select>
        <div class="flex-video widescreen vimeo">
          <iframe name = "starterVID" 
                  id = "starterVID" 
                  width="870" 
                  height="498" 
                  src="https://www.youtube.com/" 
                  frameborder="0" 
                  allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your option values should be unique.

I've used `localStorage` to store the last selected data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the text in the dropdown changes and is retained but the video within the iframe still remains the default src

Comment: I forgot to mention i also have this function to open the options in the iframe: <script type="text/javascript">
function loadFrame(url,frameId){
 document.getElementById(frameId).src = url;
}
</script>

Comment: @zxb413 I've updated the answer (`JavaScript`), have a look and let me know.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @zxb413 Welcome buddy :)